# Quel est l'inverse de « glorieux » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, antonyme

Quel est le nom de la langue française qui est exactement l'inverse de glorieux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« Honteux » et « piteux » me semblent de bons antonymes et ont le mérite de rimer avec « glorieux» .

Answer (score 3):

Il y en a toute une liste fournie par Le Robert :

Pour ce qui concerne la renommée :

> - avilissant
> - déshonorant
> - ignominieux
> - infamant
> - infâme

Par rapport à la position dans la société :

> - ignoré
> - méprisé
> - obscur

Comme composante du caractère :

> - humble
> - modeste